# scrapy and relative paths

Tags: python, scrapy

I am not straightforward with python, I have been trying for hours now to cut off few char from multiple elements in a list.  All scrapped links that I want to follow with my spider are relative, here are just few lines of my output:

```
 [u'../../../info/Auto/Dutch/']
 [u'../../../info/Automazing/All_Star/']
 [u'../../../info/AutoW/Passion/']
```

I am trying to get rid of

```
 "../../.."
```

This is my code:

```
  def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select('//div[@class="partInnerDiv"]/table/tbody/tr')
    items = []
    for link in links:
       item = myItem()
       item ['url'] = link.select('th/a/@href').extract()   
       print complete_url(item ['url'])
       items.append(item)            
    return items

  def complete_url(string):
    url = string
   #if string.startswith("../"):
   #   return string[5:]
    return url.replace('../../', '')
```

From the code above you can see that I tried few methods, but nothing works for me :(

```
   exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the `string` parameter that you are passing to the `complete_url` method is a list and not a string as you are expecting it to be.

Do this:

```
def complete_url(string):
    url = string[0]
    return url.replace('../../', '')
```

Comment: thanks for tip, I thought it might be something like that :) its painful when you don't understand the concept of a language :(

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`urlparse.urljoin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
import urlparse

urlparse.urljoin(u'http://www.mysite.com/a/b/c/', u'../../../info/Auto/Dutch/')

# => u'http://www.mysite.com/info/Auto/Dutch/'
```

In your callback it would become:

```
  def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select('//div[@class="partInnerDiv"]/table/tbody/tr')
    items = []
    for link in links:
       item = myItem()
       item ['url'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, u)
                       for u in link.select('th/a/@href').extract()]
       items.append(item)            
    return items
```

This code assumes Python 2.x; in Python 3, the function has been renamed to `urllib.parse.urljoin()`, but Scrapy does not currently work with Python 3.

Comment: I added an example on how to use `urlparse.urljoin()` within OP's code. Hope it's ok with you

Comment: @paul...thanks for help! I will reconsider urlparse.urljoin(): in next spider :)